# have problem with react useEffect function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have this update form for a place and I fetch its data from the backend to add initial inputs in useEffect but I got this error

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I know the problem is related to unmounted the component before update the state but I try many solutions but not working. Anyone have an idea how to fix that

```
const UpdatePlace = () => {
const placeId = useParams().pId;
const [loadedPlace, setLoadedPlace] = useState();
// const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const { error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();

const [isLoading, formState, inputHandler, setFormData] = useForm(
  {
    title: {
      value: "",
      isValid: false,
    },
    description: {
      value: "",
      isValid: false,
    },
  },
  true
);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPlace = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await sendRequest(`/api/places/${placeId}`);
      await setLoadedPlace(res.data.place);
      setFormData(
        {
          title: {
            value: res.data.place.title,
            isValid: true,
          },
          description: {
            value: res.data.place.description,
            isValid: true,
          },
        },
        true
      );
    } catch (err) {}
  };
  fetchPlace();
}, [sendRequest, placeId, setFormData]);

if (!loadedPlace && !error) {
  return (
    <div className="center" style={{ maxWidth: "400px", margin: "0 auto" }}>
      <Card>
        <h2>No place found!</h2>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

const placeUpdateSubmitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(formState.inputs, formState.isFormValid);
};

return (
  <>
    {isLoading ? (
      <LoadingSpinner asOverlay />
    ) : error ? (
      <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
    ) : (
      <>
        <Title label="Update place" />
        <form className="place-form" onSubmit={placeUpdateSubmitHandler}>
          <Input
            element="input"
            type="text"
            id="title"
            label="Update title"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
            errorText="please enter valid title"
            onInput={inputHandler}
            initialValue={loadedPlace.title}
            initialValid={true}
          />
          <Input
            element="textarea"
            id="description"
            label="Update description"
            validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE(), VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(5)]}
            errorText="please enter valid description (min 5 chars) "
            onInput={inputHandler}
            initialValue={loadedPlace.description}
            initialValid={true}
          />
          <Button type="submit" disabled={!formState.isFormValid}>
            Update place
          </Button>
        </form>
      </>
    )}
  </>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect with [] with cleanup function, as it will execute last one like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
 return () => {
  console.log('cleaned up');
 }
},[])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still receive the same error, and the page not render

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your request completes after you have navigated away from that page and it tries to update a component that is already unmounted. You should use an [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) to abort your request. Something like this should work:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;

  const fetchPlace = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`/api/places/${placeId}`, { signal }).then(response => {
    return response;
}).catch(e => {
    console.warn(`Fetch 1 error: ${e.message}`);
});
      await setLoadedPlace(res.data.place);
      setFormData(
        {
          title: {
            value: res.data.place.title,
            isValid: true,
          },
          description: {
            value: res.data.place.description,
            isValid: true,
          },
        },
        true
      );
    } catch (err) {}
  };
  fetchPlace();
  return () => {
    controller.abort();   
  };
}, [sendRequest, placeId, setFormData]);
```

**Edit: Fix undefined obj key/value on render**

The above warning will not stop your component from rendering. What would give you an undefined error and prevent your component from rendering is how you initiate the constant **loadedPlace**. You initiate it as null but you use it as an object inside your Input initialValue={loadedPlace.title}. When your component tries to do the first render it reads the state for that value but fails to locate the key and breaks.

Try this to fix it:

```
const placeObj = {
          title: {
            value: '',
            isValid: true,
          },
          description: {
            value: '',
            isValid: true,
          };
const [loadedPlace, setLoadedPlace] = useState(placeObj);
```

Always make sure that when you use an object you don't use undefined keys upon render.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still receive the same error, and the page not render

Comment: This is not an error, this is a warning. It doesn't prevent your app from rendering it's content. Your problem is probably in your definition of loadedPlace. Give me 2 minutes to update my answer to fix that for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer that is really useful information, but I found the problem with the page that leads to this component in the useEffect where I made async action without initializing a function inside it